# How many 7 digit numbers with different digits can be formed, without a $2$ in the units place or the hundreds place?

Tags: combinatorics

How many $7$ digit numbers with different digits can be formed, so that they don't have a $2$ in the units place or the hundreds place?

For example, $1345762$ or $1783296$ are not valid.

Comment: Do the digits have to be different?

Comment: What have you attempted?  Where are you stuck?  Please edit your question to include this information.

Answer (score 2):

7290000 numbers. units digit can be 9 different numbers, tens digit can be 10 different numbers, hundreds digit can be 9 different numbers, thousands digit can be 10 different numbers, 10 thousands digit can be 10 different numbers, 100 thousands digit can be 10 different numbers, and the million digit can be 9 different numbers.

Comment: The digits are supposed to be distinct.